# Replacing Func Parameter with Tuple

Tags: swift, function, parameters, tuples, variadic

Swift
I must be misunderstanding something

```
func test(_ x: 0, y: 0) { /* code */ }

let a = test
test(x: 1, y: 2) // This is ok
```

I'm trying to pass in tuples in replacement for parameters.

```
a.(x: 0, y: 0) // Not ok
a.(0, 0) // Not ok

let b = (x: 1, y: 2)
a.b // This is also not ok
```

I'm hoping to use variadic parameters and tuples for something cool like this:

```
func test(_ x: Int...) { /* code */ }
test.(0)
test.(0, 0, 0)
test.(0, 1, 2, 3)

let tuple = (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
test.tuple
```

I feel like this should work

Comment: When I place a "." after the value, Swift allows me to do this. But then it throws errors..

Comment: What’s the question?

Comment: @matt - func hello(a: Int) {} --- hello(a: 5)  --- I see the (a: 5) as a tuple. If I put a period after "hello" like this: "hello." it gives me the option to add self, or add parameters. I was wondering if I could use a tuple instead, since parameters are tuples. --- Sorry, I hope this helps.

Comment: @jonathan, till Xcode 7 it was possible to pass the tuple as input parameter to function (type, number of parameters should match, won't work for defalut and optional ). but it's no longer possible.

Comment: Thank you so much, @RubiyaFaniband! I'm going to find that change in the Swift Evolution in GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you pass parameters to function inside round parenthesis and not with dot (.)

if you want to pass tuple to a function you do it like this a((0, 0))

if you want to pass tuple of unknown size to a function you can use generics.
the drawback of this solution is that you handle only fixed number of tuple lengths.
I cannot think of better way to do it...

for example:

```
func f<T>(_ arg : T) {
    if arg is (Int) { print ("1") }
    if arg is (Int, Int) { print ("2") }
    if arg is (Int, Int, Int) { print ("3") }
    ...
    if arg is (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int) { print ("7") }
}
let x = (1, 2)
f(x)
// prints 2
```

Comment: Sweet! This is great! I can turn the "ifs" into a switch statement, then check for cases of (_, Int, _, _) and other syntactic sugar. Awesome, thank you!